# Changing Kivy Button Properties in Another Screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm having a very hard time trying to figure out how to change a button's `disabled` property on another screen and I would like to understand this problem.

Let's say that you have a login screen in the app, where the account that logs has an attribute called `prof` that is a `Boolean` value, so it can be either True or False. The Home page of the app has a button, that based of that same attribute it knows if it has to be enabled or not. I tried so many ways but I didn't manage to come up with a solution, can you help me?

Here is the Home page Kv code (all of those Space and TitleLabel are custom elements made by me):

```
<Home>:
    name: "home"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
        size_hint: .7, 1

        TitleLabel:
            text: "Home"
            font_size: 50

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

            Button:
                text: "FAQ"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "faq_ap"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

            Space:

            Button:
                text: "Gestionale"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "gest_red"

            Space:

            Button:
                text: "Gestionale Prof."
                disabled: root.btn_disabled
                opacity: 1
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "gest_nom"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

            Space:

            Button:
                text: "Account"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "account"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

            Space:
```

Here is the Home class:

```
class Home(Screen):
    """
    Classe Home.
    """
    def prof(self):
        with open("account_prof.txt", "r") as f:
            prof = f.readline()

            # print(self.ids.gestionale_prof)
            if prof == "True":
                pass
            else:
                pass
```

And here are the Login class and Kv code if you need them:

```
class LoginPage(Screen):
    """
    Classe che si occupa del login dell'utente.
    """
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)
    valid = False

    def delete_info(self):
        """
        Questa funzione semplicemente rende i campi d'inserimento vuoti.
        """
        self.email.text = ''
        self.password.text = ''

    def log_into_account(self):
        """
        Questa funzione controlla se l'utente già esiste nel database.
        """
        with ps.connect(dbname=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS, host=DB_HOST) as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cur:
                try:
                    # Cerca l'utente nel database.
                    cur.execute(
                        f'''SELECT email, password, prof from "'{self.email.text}'" WHERE email = '{self.email.text}' ''')
                    credentials = cur.fetchone()
                    # Controlla se l'account creato è professionale
                    prof = credentials[2]
                    if self.password.text == credentials[1]:
                        with open('account_email.txt', 'w') as f:
                            f.write(f'{self.email.text}')
                        with open('account_prof.txt', 'w') as f:
                            f.write(f'{prof}')
                        self.valid = True
                        return self.valid
                    else:
                        invalid_login_info()
                        self.valid = False
                        return self.valid
                except:
                    invalid_login_info()
                    self.valid = False
                    return self.valid

    def login(self):
        """
        Questa funzione controlla se entrambi i campi sono stati compilati
        e se lo sono allora procede a cercare l'utente nel database.
        """
        if self.email.text != '' and self.email.text != '':
            self.log_into_account()
            return self.valid
        else:
            self.valid = False
            invalid_login_info()
            return self.valid
```

Here's the Kv code:

```
<LoginPage>:
    name: "login"

    email: email
    password: password

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
        size_hint: .7, 1

        TitleLabel:
            text: "Login"
            font_size: 50

        SubTitleLabel:
            text: "Email:"

        TextInput:
            id: email
            multiline: False

        SubTitleLabel:
            text: "Password:"

        TextInput:
            id: password
            multiline: False
            password: True

        Space:

        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "home" if root.login() else "login"
                root.delete_info()
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        Space:

        Button:
            halign: "center"
            text: "Crea un account"
            on_release:
                root.delete_info()
                app.root.current = "signup"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

        Space:
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing the main problem.

Comment: Ok, it will take a little bit but I should be capable.

Comment: By enabled, do you mean you want to add a widget? Or you will have the widget there, but it won't have a function until the boolean is true?

Comment: It's the same for me, it can be either one or the other. If you take the second option, the button should also be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

**In ur kv file**

```
<loginscreen>
    TextInput:
        id: user   
        hint_text: ' Enter a Username'
    TextInput:
        id: password   
        hint_text: ' Enter a password'
    Button:
        text: 'Submit'
        on_press: root.btn_submit()
<somescreen>
    Button:
        id: target
        text: 'some_btn'
```

**In ur main.py**

```
some_cond = False

class Loginscreen(Widget):              
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        global some_cond   
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def btn_submit(self):   
        if self.ids.user.text == somestring and self.ids.password.text == someotherstring:
            theapp.screenm.current = 'somescreen'
            some_cond = True
        else:
           pass

class somescreen(Widget):                       
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        global some_cond
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedual_interval(update_some_cond, 1)
        
    def update_some_cond(self, *args):
        global some_cond
        if some_cond == True:
            self.ids.targer.disabled = True
            Clock.unschedule(update_some_cond)
        else:
            pass

class theapp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.Loginscreen = Loginscreen()
        screen = Screen(name="loginscreen")
        screen.add_widget(self.Loginscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)
        
        self.somescreen = somescreen()
        screen = Screen(name = "somescreen")
        screen.add_widget(self.somescreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    theapp = theapp()
    theapp.start()
```

and There are Many other ways. but when working with kivy its better to work with Clocks to update variables the `some_cond` variable needs to be updated on `class somescreen` so that the button is enabled. u can say `if loginscreen.some_cond == True:` `self.ids.target.disabled = False` but like i told u clocks are essential.